# How does one package a fork of Wagtail for installation?

Tags: wagtail

I have a fork of Wagtail that I need to install into my Docker container for deployment to production. In dev, I've been using a complicated combination of building the static resources, mounting the git repo into my container, and then running `manage.py collectstatic`, but that's clearly not going to work in prod.

So I somehow need to do whatever it is that the Wagtail devs do when they package Wagtail for release on PyPI (or something to that effect). I have no experience in this, and thus I haven't got the faintest clue how that might be accomplished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the root of your Wagtail git checkout (and assuming the tooling for building the static assets has previously been installed using `npm install`), run:

```
python ./setup.py sdist
```

This will create a .tar.gz package within `dist/`, which can be installed with `pip`. For remote deployments, it's usually most convenient to upload this to a public URL somewhere and place that URL in your project's requirements in place of the standard `wagtail` line.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: I got a syntax error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file setup.py` and had to add `# coding: utf-8` at the top of `setup.py` file.

Comment: @JeanZombie Python 3 is utf-8 by default, so that probably means you had a Python 2 environment active.

Comment: True. I did not noticed that my virtual env was not activated.